# Is there a better alternative for the following OOP design?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have a collection of classes, call them `Derived1, Derived2, ..., Derived6`, each of which is a subclass of a base class `Base`. These classes are defined in a third-party Java package.

I'm writing a class that will write out a human-readable representations of these objects. I approached the problem as follows: define methods `String transform(Derivedi object)`, for each `i=1,2,...,6`, and `String transform(Base object)`.

The problem occurs when, for example, `Base obj = new Derived3(...)` and I want to compute the representation for `obj`. The expression `transform(obj)` invokes the method with signature `String transform(Base)`, which has to call the "right" method (in this case the one with the signature `String transform(Derived3)`).

The method `String transform(Base object)` delegates work to the appropriate method via a sequence of conditional statements of the form `if (obj instanceof Derivedi)` for each `i=1,2,...,6`. (If I had control over the package I would have an abstract method `String toReadable()` on the base class, which every derived class would have to implement; unfortunately in this case I have no control over the package.)

I don't like this solution (it's easy to see why). What would be the alternatives to this implementation of `String transform(Base)`?

Comment: I don't understand how this problem can possibly arise. Have you considered overriding the `toString()` method? Or another simple override within the class hierarchy you've described? Instead of somewhere else that needs a parameter?

Comment: That is not polymorphism. Polymorphism would consist in having a toHumanRepresentation() method in each class, which would transform `this` into a human representation. If you don't have any control over the classes, except for instanceof checks, there's not much you can do.

Comment: This isn't polymorphism, polymorphism would be invoking the same method on all of the objects (like the toReadable() approach you mention). There's a built in Java mechanism for this, every Class has a toString() method inherited from Object that can be overridden for class specific behavior, maybe the classes given to you override it. If not, you have to resort to a non-OO solution, such as an if-else sequence. Keep in mind that whenever you have a switch-case, or as in this case its ugly if-else sequence cousin, you can replace it with a map from the value that you're checking to actions.

Answer (score 1):

You could try and provide transformers (the objects that contain `transform(...)`) per class. Then maintain a map that maps the transformers to those classes (assuming the transformers themselves are stateless).

Example:

```
class Transformer {
  Class<? extends Base> getTransformableClass() { ... }
  String transform( Base obj ){ 
    //check and cast obj to the actual type then create the string
  }
}

Map<Class<?>, Transformer> transformers = ...;
Transformer base = new BaseTransformer(); //the same for derived
transformers.put( base.getTransformableClass(), base );
```

Note that with CDI/Reflection you could do the lookup somewhat automatically (i.e. lookup all classes that implement a certain interface or are annotated with a certain annotation).

Then use it like this:

```
public String transform( Base obj) {
  //add null checks etc.

  return transformers.get(obj.getClass()).transform(obj);
}
```

Further note that generics might help when implementing the transformers but using them from the map would then make some casts/raw types necessary since you'd not know the actual type you get from the map, i.e. you as the developer know that `transformers.get( Derived1.class )` should return a transformer being able to handle `Derived1` instances but the compiler doesn't know that and thus needs you to handle that and cast appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use getSimpleName() to get the name of the class, and use a switch statement on the name. You will still need this delegation to be done in `transform(Base object)` but is will be somewhat cleaner than several if statements and instanceof checks.